# Synchronizing When Deleting Or Updating an IO File

Tags: java, file-io, lucene

Specifically I am using lucene to perform full text searching and in certain scenarios the index file might become corrupted or simply has not been created yet at which point I would delete the file and rewrite the index to said file. My question pertains to the actual act of deleting and re-writing to a file in a multi threaded Java program.

Will synchronizing protect the IO File while its being deleted and restored? In other words will it block access to another thread coming along and attempting to use the same method and begin rewriting while its already in the process?

The setDirectory method needs to be run before any other methods in the class will work (it will throw errors otherwise), so does the way I have the synchronization setup protect me from any multi threaded mishaps?

When another thread attempts to use the setDirectory method and the buildCompleteIndex method is already in progress, will the thread simply wait for that to finish and then its check on whether the path exists will pass and it will move on to opening the index?

In lucene do I have to synchronize when writing, deleting, or searching the index or can these tasks be done concurrently?

```
public void setDirectory(int organizationId) throws IOException {
    this.organizationId = organizationId;
    File path = new File(INDEX_PATH + "/" + String.valueOf(organizationId));

    //If path does not exist, create it and create new index for organization
    synchronized(this) {
        if(!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
            buildCompleteIndex(organizationId, false);
        }
    }

    this.directory = FSDirectory.open(path); //Open directory
}

private void buildCompleteIndex(int organizationId, boolean rebuildDir) {
    if(rebuildDir) {
        File path = new File(INDEX_PATH + "/" + String.valueOf(organizationId));
        try {
            Utils.deleteDirectory(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new LuceneIndexException("Error rebuilding index directory.", e);
        }
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    List<Tag> tagList = tagDAO.findAll(organizationId);
    for(Tag tag : tagList) {
        add(tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your synchronized(this) clause will help to get calls to setDirectory() to block and verify that path exists or rebuild the index. It does not deal with any other users of an older index while it is being rebuilt. Also it is safer to synchronize on a private value as other code can break your synchronization by calling notify or notifyAll on your monitor. You could promote path to be an instance variable and synchronize on it for example.

Comment: You synchronize on _this_. And second user can create second instance of your class. Is it singleton? You store name of directory in `this.directory`. Two threads can call this method and in directory will be only one assign (even if all method will be synchronized). The thread do not know if the directory contains right value, because method setDirectory can be called second time. Make class immutable and initialize all in constructor